# How to make a .mobileconfig/profile that donwloads a .app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile-config

How to make a .mobileconfig/profile that downloads a .app file. I have an app that is not for the public, just for friends and i want to make a easy way for them to download for free.

I have searched all over internet without finding how.

Comment: I also tried make a download link to the .app file on a website but it made either the file as appname.app.html or when i tried to use google drive it made it an appname.app.zip and it just go to files app on iphone.

Comment: You can't. You will need the UDID of their devices and then add these to your developer account and provisioning profile for your app. You can then sign an ipa file and send it to your friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t.

As of 2022 Apple supports [Unlisted Apps](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/). But you would need to join [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/).